# Jquery get specific form elements by id into a string

Tags: jquery

i have a form that generates dynamic text inputs with ids like follows

`<input id='item_blue_1' ...
    <input id='item_green_2' ...
    <input id='item_blue_3' ...
    <input id='item_green_4' ...
    <input id='item_blue_5' ...`

how can i get all the values of only the elements that start with ids item_green, and put the values into a coma separated string or array, which ever is fastest and easiest?

Comment: Can we see the full generated HTML? There's probably a much neater way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use start with selector

```
var arr=[];
var ids=$("[id^=item_green]");
arr = $.map(ids, function(n, index){
  return ($(ids).eq(index).val());
});

var stringArr=arr.join(","); //for string values
```

Comment: This will select the input elements but it won't give you the values.

Comment: how hard it is to get the values after selecting anyway now it gives the values too

Comment: @Surreal Dreams fair enough `:)`

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = new Array();
$('input[id^="item_green"]').each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).val());
});
return arr; // or return arr.join(",") for a string
```

Comment: Tried this solution and was breaking my head for over half hour cause this wasnt working.. for those who get stuck like me- take notice that it shud be ^= and not =^=

Comment: fixed - not sure how that extra = got in there

Answer (score 1):

use following:

```
var joinedString = $('input[id^=item_green]').map(function(){
       return $(this).val();
    }).get().join(",");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E86e5/3/

Comment: Best solution. +1 using map and get the result in an Array.

Answer (score 0):

There are jquery selectors you can use to find elements that have attributes staring with a certain string. Here is an example:

```
var values = new Array();   
$('[id^=item_green]').each(function() { values.push($(this).val());});
```

Then `values` will be an array filled with all the values.